# Graph is tree checking

Tags: java, graph, tree

--I have written code for checking whether the graph given as adjacency list in input file is a tree or not and outputting it out onto output file.

--The comments explain the operation happening at every stage.

--adjacencyList.get(no_of_vertices) = new ArrayList(); line is giving a compilation error as

```
The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
```

--Could anyone point out at the code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class isTree implements Comparator<Integer> {

    /* Variables used ::
       (1) adjacencyList  -- Contains the adjacency list as an array after being extracted from list. Each row contains all vertices connected 
                            to the corresponding vertex given by row.
       (2) no_of_edges    -- Contains number of edges in the graph
       (3) no_of_vertices -- Contains number of vertices in graph
       (4) result         -- Contains whether a graph is a tree or not
     */
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adjacencyList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(100);
    int no_of_edges=0;
    int no_of_vertices=0;
    String result;

    /* Operation control function which calls all other functions on the graph input provided. */
    private isTree(String input_file,String output_file){
        createArrayList(input_file);    
        no_of_edges = findingEdges(adjacencyList);
        if(!result.equals("Not a Tree")){
            if(checkCondition1(no_of_edges,no_of_vertices) && checkCondition2(adjacencyList,no_of_vertices))
                result = "Its a Tree";
            else
                result = "Not a Tree";
        }
       printingResultInFile(output_file); 
    }

    /* Creation of ArrayList from the input File by extracting line by line and using comma delimiter to split the numbers in each line
       which are then stored as vertices in increasing order in the adjacency row of the list. */
    private void createArrayList(String input_name){
        int j;
        String line;
        String [] vertices;
        Scanner in=null;
        int len;
        try {
            in = new Scanner(new File(input_name));
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
        }
        while(in.hasNextLine()){
            List<Integer> rowList = adjacencyList.get(no_of_vertices);
        rowList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        line = in.nextLine();
        if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("null")){
            no_of_vertices++;
            continue;
        }
        vertices = line.split(",");
        len = vertices.length;
        for(j=0;j<len;j++){
            rowList.add(Integer.parseInt(vertices[j]));
        }
        Collections.sort(rowList);
        no_of_vertices++;
        }
    }
    public int compare(Integer a,Integer b){
           if(a >= b)
               return 1;
           else 
               return -1;
    }

    /* Finding number of edges by calculating the total number of vertices in all the rows of adjacency list and dividing by 2 since edge 
       edge relation is symmetric. */

    private int findingEdges(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adjacencyList){
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<no_of_vertices;i++){
            if(adjacencyList.get(i).contains(i)){
                result = "Not a Tree";
                return -1;
              }
            else{
                no_of_edges = no_of_edges+adjacencyList.get(i).size();
            }
        }
        no_of_edges = no_of_edges/2;
        return no_of_edges;
    }

    /* Takes in 2 inputs firstly 'e' which is the number of edges and secondly 'v' which is number of vertices
       in the graph. Since a tree satisfies e = v - 1 relation we are checking this relation in the function */

    private boolean checkCondition1(int no_of_edges,int no_of_vertices){
        if(no_of_edges == no_of_vertices - 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    /* Implementing Depth First Search as explained below:
       (1)Pushes vertex 1 to the stack.
       (2)Checks if vertex 1 is not there in template list and adds.
       (3)It pops vertex 1 out and adds it to template
       (4)It pushes all vertices connected to 1 to stack if they are not present on template list.  
       (5)It pops a vertex from stack and adds it to template list and adds all its connected vertices to 
          the stack if they are not present in the template list.
       (6)This is repeated until the stack is empty. 
    */ 
    private boolean checkCondition2(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adjacencyList,int no_of_vertices){
        pArrayStackInt stack = new pArrayStackInt(no_of_vertices);
        int j=1,k;
        ArrayList<Integer> template = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        stack.push(1);
        while(!stack.isEmpty()){
            j=stack.pop();
            template.add(j);
            Iterator<Integer> itr = adjacencyList.get(j-1).iterator();
            j++;
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                k=itr.next();
                if(!template.contains(k))
                    stack.push(k);
            }

        }
        if(template.size()==no_of_vertices)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    /* Printing whether the given input file is a tree or not onto the output file depending upon the value stored
       in result variable */

    private void printingResultInFile(String output_file){
        PrintWriter out=null;
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(output_file);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
        }
        out.write(result);
        out.close();
    }

    /* 2 inputs are provided at the runtime as arguments firstly input_file name and secondly output file name.
       Input file name is stored in args[0] and Output file name is stored in args[1]. With these input file name
       and output file name a new instance of isTree is created */

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String input_file = args[0];
        String output_file = args[1];
        new isTree(input_file,output_file);
    }
}
 /* Implementing stack data structure by providing push, pop and isEmpty operations */
 class pArrayStackInt{
    private int head[];
    private int pointer;

    public pArrayStackInt(int capacity){
        head = new int[capacity];
        pointer = -1;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return pointer == -1;
    }
    public void push(int i){
        if(pointer+1 < head.length)
            head[++pointer] = i;
    }
    public int pop(){
        return head[pointer--];
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `List<Integer> someName = adjacencyList.get(no_of_vertices);`
The `.get()` returns an `ArrayList<Integer>` which you must save off to another variable to use it later.

Comment: I did try your suggestion and passed input and output files as command line inputs but it is giving me this error::Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
 at isTree.createArrayList(isTree.java:57)
 at isTree.<init>(isTree.java:32)
 at isTree.main(isTree.java:161)

Comment: Now that's another issue completely. You are trying to reach out to a place on the array that is greater than the length of the array.